# C# / Entity Framework - Dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework to develop a web based application. I originally generated the model as "Code First' from an existing database. However, I have modified the database structure since then and have, correspondingly updated the Entity Framework classess. One of these manual edits included the adding of a class "Employee".

Whenever I attempt to execute this code:

```
        using (ApplicationModel dbContext = new ApplicationModel())
        {
            Applicant applicant = dbContext.Applicants.First(a => a.ID == applicantID);
            applicant.Hired = true;

            // Transfer Data to New Hire
            Employee newHire = new Employee();
            newHire.Applicant = applicant;
            newHire.CellPhone = (applicant.CellPhone == null) ? "" : applicant.CellPhone;
            newHire.City = applicant.City;
            newHire.CurrentLocation = applicant.Store;
            newHire.Email = applicant.Email;
            newHire.FirstName = applicant.FirstName;
            newHire.LastName = applicant.LastName;
            newHire.Login = applicant.Email;
            newHire.MiddleInitial = applicant.MiddleInitial;
            newHire.Password = applicant.SSN;
            newHire.Phone = applicant.Phone;
            newHire.State = applicant.State;
            newHire.StreetAddress = applicant.StreetAddress;
            newHire.Zip = applicant.Zip;

            dbContext.Employees.Add(newHire);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

I receive the following error:

```
A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column. Column: 'EmployeeID'.
```

The Employee Model is as follows:

```
public partial class Employee
{

  [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }

    public int ApplicantID { get; set; }

    public int CurrentLocationID { get; set; }

    public bool CompletedNewEmpData { get; set; }

    public bool ModuleOneComplete { get; set; }

    public bool ModuleTwoComplete { get; set; }

    public string DOB { get; set; }


    public string Login { get; set;  }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(2)]
    public string MiddleInitial { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "text")]
    public string StreetAddress { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [StringLength(2)]
    public string State { get; set; }

    [StringLength(5)]
    public string Zip { get; set; }

    [StringLength(60)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string CellPhone { get; set; }

    public string SSN { get; set; }


    public string MaritalStatus { get; set; }

    public string Residency { get; set; }

    public char Sex { get; set; }

    public string Race { get; set; }

    public string AlienNumber { get; set; }


    public string NewHireNumber { get; set; }

    public string ResponsibleManagerName { get; set; }

    public bool Rehired { get; set; }

    public decimal? PayRate { get; set; }

    public bool SaintLouisResident { get; set; }

    public string FedStatus { get; set; }

    public string StateStatus { get; set; }

    public decimal? FederalAllowances { get; set; }

    public decimal? StateAllowances { get; set; }

    public decimal? FederalAdditional { get; set; }

    public decimal? StateAdditional { get; set; }

    public string PaySelection { get; set; }

    public string PaySelectionSignature { get; set; }

    public string PaySelectionDate { get; set; }

    public string PaySelectionAccountType { get; set; }

    public string PaySelectionAccountNumber { get; set; }

    public string PaySelectionRoutingNumber { get; set; }

    public string PaySelectionCheck { get; set; }

    public string MoneyNetworkInitials { get; set; }

    public string DirectDepositInitials { get; set; }
    public string WorkCompSignature { get; set; }

    public string WorkCompSignatureDate { get; set; }

    public string JobDescriptionSignature { get; set; }

    public string JobDescriptionSignatureDate { get; set; }

    public string MemoSignature { get; set; }

    public string MemoSignatureDate { get; set; }

    public string CriminalCheckSignature { get; set; }

    public string CriminalCheckDate { get; set; }

    public string AgeAcknowledgmentSig { get; set; }

    public string AgeAcknowledgmentSigDate { get; set; }

    public string HarassmentPolicySignature { get; set; }

    public string HarassmentPolicyDate { get; set; }

    public string HandbookSignature { get; set; }

    public string HandbookSignatureDate { get; set; }

    public string DatingPolicySignature { get; set; }

    public string DatingPolicyDate { get; set; }

    public string UniformReceiptDate { get; set; }

    public string UniformReceiptSignature { get; set; }

    public string UniformItemList { get; set; }
    public decimal? UniformValue { get; set; }

    public virtual Applicant Applicant { get; set; }

    public virtual Store CurrentLocation { get; set; }

}
```

}

The ApplicationModel class is as follows:

```
public partial class ApplicationModel : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationModel()
        : base("name=ApplicationModel")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Applicant> Applicants { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<DistrictManager> DistrictManagers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Division> Divisions { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Education> Educations { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<EmergencyContact> EmergencyContacts { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<PropertyType> PropertyTypes { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<QuestionOption> QuestionOptions { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Question> Questions { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<QuestionType> QuestionTypes { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Reference> References { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Store> Stores { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<UserLevel> UserLevels { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Applicant>()
            .Property(e => e.FirstName)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Applicant>()
            .Property(e => e.LastName)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Applicant>()
            .Property(e => e.MiddleInitial)
            .IsFixedLength()
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Applicant>()
            .Property(e => e.SSN)
            .IsFixedLength()
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Applicant>()
            .Property(e => e.StreetAddress)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Applicant>()
            .Property(e => e.City)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Applicant>()
            .Property(e => e.State)
            .IsFixedLength()
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Applicant>()
            .Property(e => e.Zip)
            .IsFixedLength()
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Applicant>()
            .Property(e => e.Email)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Applicant>()
            .Property(e => e.Phone)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Applicant>()
            .Property(e => e.CellPhone)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Applicant>()
            .Property(e => e.HowHear)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Applicant>()
            .Property(e => e.Score)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Applicant>()
            .HasMany(e => e.EmergencyContacts)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Applicant)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<DistrictManager>()
            .Property(e => e.Phone)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<DistrictManager>()
            .Property(e => e.Email)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Division>()
            .Property(e => e.Description)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Education>()
            .Property(e => e.Name)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Education>()
            .Property(e => e.Location)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Education>()
            .Property(e => e.GPA)
            .HasPrecision(3, 1);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Education>()
            .Property(e => e.SchoolType)
            .IsUnicode(false);


        modelBuilder.Entity<EmergencyContact>()
            .Property(e => e.Name)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<EmergencyContact>()
            .Property(e => e.Address)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<EmergencyContact>()
            .Property(e => e.HomePhone)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<EmergencyContact>()
            .Property(e => e.WorkPhone)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<EmergencyContact>()
            .Property(e => e.Relationship)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
         .HasRequired(e => e.Applicant)
         .WithOptional(e => e.Employee);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PropertyType>()
            .Property(e => e.Description)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<QuestionOption>()
            .Property(e => e.Letter)
            .IsFixedLength()
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<QuestionOption>()
            .Property(e => e.OptionText)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Question>()
            .Property(e => e.QuestionText)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<QuestionType>()
            .Property(e => e.Description)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<QuestionType>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Questions)
            .WithOptional(e => e.QuestionType1)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.QuestionType);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Reference>()
            .Property(e => e.Name)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Reference>()
            .Property(e => e.Phone)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Reference>()
            .Property(e => e.ReferenceType)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Store>()
            .Property(e => e.Email)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Store>()
            .Property(e => e.Phone)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Store>()
            .Property(e => e.Address)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserLevel>()
            .Property(e => e.Description)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserLevel>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Users)
            .WithRequired(e => e.UserLevel1)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserLevel)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasMany(e => e.DistrictManagers)
            .WithRequired(e => e.User)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

}

While, I am not denying the very real possibility that it is an obvious, simple mistake, I have looked around (including here: [A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384659/a-dependent-property-in-a-referentialconstraint-is-mapped-to-a-store-generated-c)) and could not find any answer to my problems. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: take a look on [this](https://ihadthisideaonce.com/2012/01/18/manually-creating-referential-constraints-in-entity-framework-4/) see if it helps

Comment: Check if you have `EmployeeID` property in `Employee` table as foreign key relationship target with primary key property in other table. It may involving one-to-one relationship with table primary key set as foreign key to other table's primary key.