# Computed Column as Foreign Key

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-database-first

I am getting an error:

> A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column. Column: LanguageId

I am using Entity Framework with a database-first approach, and have a relationship where a foreign key contains the column `LanguageId` (which is a computed column).

Is there any workaround or solution for this? I need this column to be computed and I need for it to be included in the foreign key.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @TheImpaler See yellow box.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384659/a-dependent-property-in-a-referentialconstraint-is-mapped-to-a-store-generated-c)